# How do I add a class to the active tab in an accordion using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I made this jfiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/yp9v5/1/

I'm trying to add a class to the open tab (class is set to the first tab which is open on page load and then switched to another tab when it is clicked).  I want to be able to style the active tab differently.

I have tried using addClass but I don't think i'm using it correctly to add the class to the active label.

Here is the jQuery I used:

```
    jQuery(".alt_block_wrapper .ac-container div label").click(function() {

    jQuery(".alt_block_wrapper .ac-container div article").css("display", "none");
    jQuery(this).parent().find("article").fadeIn("slow");
    jQuery(this).addClass("ac-active");
});
jQuery(".alt_block_wrapper .ac-container div article").css("display", "none");
jQuery(".alt_block_wrapper .ac-container div article").first().css("display", "block");
```

and the html:

```
<div class="alt_block_wrapper one-third">
        <section class="ac-container">
            <div>
                <input id="ac-1412" name="accordion-1412" type="radio" checked />
                <label for="ac-1412">First Tab</label>
                <article class="ac-medium">
                    <p>Nostraaptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="ac-2412" name="accordion-1412" type="radio" />
                <label for="ac-2412">Second Tab</label>
                <article class="ac-medium">
                    <p>Nostraaptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="ac-3412" name="accordion-1412" type="radio" />
                <label for="ac-3412">Third Tab</label>
                <article class="ac-medium">
                    <p>Nostraaptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="ac-4412" name="accordion-1412" type="radio" />
                <label for="ac-4412">Fourth Tab</label>
                <article class="ac-medium">
                    <p>Nostraaptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="ac-5412" name="accordion-1412" type="radio" />
                <label for="ac-5412">Fifth Tab</label>
                <article class="ac-medium">
                    <p>Nostraaptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                </article>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: why do you want to do that? You already have another class added to it that differentiates it from the rest of the tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is mainly due to Css specifity. Yes, you are already applying the class, but it is overridden by another rule applied on the `label` which overrides `.classname` rule anyways. So your syle is not getting applied.

Add this to your rule

```
label.ac-active {
    border-color:red;
}
```

Instead of

```
.ac-active {
        border-color:red;  // if you add !important then it will work too, but not recommended to use that when you have a way to resolve it without it.
    }
```

And in the script:

```
// Remove class from other tab which is already active and apply to the current tab.
jQuery('.ac-active').not(jQuery(this).addClass("ac-active")).removeClass('ac-active');
```

Instead of

```
 jQuery(this).addClass("ac-active");
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mw8sv/)

What happened in your case is the border color applied by `.ac-container label{` overrides the rule applied on the label with the class `.ac-active`. Plus the above script will remove the class from any previously selected tabs `ac-active` class.

Couple of good reads; [this](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) and [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html)

Comment: Ahh yes, I see.  Was that ac-active class being applied though in my original example and just being overwritten?  One more thing though, the ac-active class needs to be on the open/active one when the page loads as well and it only shows up once one is clicked.

Comment: @fender967 For styling the default tab either you can provide the class in the markup for the first div or just put this `
jQuery('.ac-container > div').eq(0).find("label[for]").addClass('ac-active');` in document.ready. See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KgxJw/

Comment: For the first question, yes style on the tagname takes precedence over the classname. I have some links in my answer on css specificity you may want to look at.

Comment: Ah thanks, well both of you were right but ill give it to you since you were first

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tGbSV/)

What you need just change the css of "ac-active" increase his weight:

```
.ac-container label.ac-active {border-color:red;}
```

Updated Script:

```
mainElement= ".alt_block_wrapper .ac-container div";
$(mainElement).find("article").css("display", "none").first().css("display", "block").prev().addClass('ac-active'); 

$(mainElement).find("label").click(function() {
    $this=$(this);
    $(mainElement).find("article").hide(); // Hide all Elements
    $(mainElement).find("label").removeClass('ac-active'); // Hide all Elements
    $this.addClass('ac-active').parent().find("article").fadeIn("slow"); //current parent element
});
```